# How should I navigate to a JSON file in react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, path, filepath, react-native-fs

So, I am using this:

```
RNFS.writeFile('./work.json', JSON.stringify(workData));
```

And the ./work.json path is apparently not working, error:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './work.json'`
, tho it it works in require() statements, Any ideas?, I have tried everything.

**Note:** I am trying to navigate this on the phone, **OS: IOS**

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a file at run time, you need to put it in a directory your app has access to. RNFS gives you `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath`, which is a directory, writable by your app in both iOS and android.

```
const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath  + '/work.json';
RNFS.writeFile(path, JSON.stringify(workData));
```

Comment: It did not work: ```Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/F25815D2-B9CD-4158-A04A-C97489960BC0/Documents./work.json'```

Comment: Sorry about the sloppy copy and paste - remove the '.' from './work.json'. I've edited the answer to reflect this.